read and write two files in one step in one file
I am doing a spring batch project in which I have to read and modify several TXT files and write them in a new file in JSON format. I created my steps for each file, they are written one after the other. However, the last two have a link, the cities, and history files. Some cities have a history, and it would be necessary for each city if a history has the same postal code as it, then its history is rewritten following this one. And I'm stuck a little, I don't know if I should rewrite a step for each or if I should do both in the same step. At the moment, I have this:

  @Bean
  public Job runjob(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager) throws Exception{
    return new JobBuilder("runJob", jobRepository)
        .start(stepCountry(jobRepository,txManager))
        .next(stepRegion(jobRepository,txManager))
        .next(stepDepartment(jobRepository,txManager))
        .next(stepCity(jobRepository,txManager))
        .next(stepHistorique(jobRepository,txManager))
        .build(); 
}

for the moment, all my @Beans are in one class config
  @Bean
  public Step stepCity(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager)throws Exception{
    return new StepBuilder("stepCity")
            .repository(jobRepository)
            .<City, City>chunk(25)
            .reader(readerCity())
            .processor(processorCity())
            .writer(writerCity())
            .transactionManager(txManager)
            .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public Step stepHistorique(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager txManager)throws Exception{
    return new StepBuilder("stepHistorique")
            .repository(jobRepository)
            .<Historique, Historique>chunk(25)
            .reader(readerHistorique())
            .processor(processorHistorique())
            .writer(writerHistorique())
            .transactionManager(txManager)
            .build();
  }

I did not put what concerns my processor and my other files because it is not important for what I want to do currently

@Bean
  public ItemReader<City> readerCity() throws Exception{
    FlatFileItemReader<City> readerCity = new FlatFileItemReader<City>();
    readerCity.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
      setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
        setNames(new String[]{"typecom","com","reg","dep","arr","tncc","ncc","nccenr","libelle","can","comparent"});
      }});
      setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<City>() {{
        setTargetType(City.class);
      }});
    }});
    readerCity.setResource(new ClassPathResource("documents/Cities.txt"));
    return readerCity;
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader readerHistorique() throws Exception{
    FlatFileItemReader readerHistorique = new FlatFileItemReader();
    readerHistorique.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper() {{
      setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
        setNames(new String[]{"mod","date_eff","typecom_av","com_av","tncc_av","ncc_av","nccenr_av","libelle_av","typecom_ap","com_ap"
            ,"tncc_ap","ncc_ap","nccenr_ap", "libelle_ap"});
      }});
      setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper() {{
        setTargetType(Historique.class);
      }});
    }});
    readerHistorique.setResource(new ClassPathResource("documents/HistoriqueCities.txt"));
    System.out.println(readerHistorique);
    return readerHistorique;
  }

I think it is necessary for everyone to have an ItemReader
  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<City> writerCity() {
    JsonFileItemWriter<City> writerCity = new JsonFileItemWriter<>(
        new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/Insee.json"),
        new JsonObjectMarshaller<City>() {
          @Override
          public String marshal(City object) {
            try {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
              return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;
            }
          }
        }) {
      @Override
      public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
          throws ItemStreamException {
        super.open(executionContext);
        try {
          getOutputState().write(",{Cities: }[");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    };
    writerCity.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/Insee.json"));
    writerCity.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writerCity.setJsonObjectMarshaller(new JsonObjectMarshaller<City>() {
      @Override
      public String marshal(City item) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("status", item.getTypecom());
        map.put("insee", item.getCom());
        map.put("parent", item.getComparent());
        map.put("country", item.getCountry());
        map.put("dept", item.getDep());

        return map.toString();
      }
    });
    return writerCity;
  }

@Bean
  public ItemWriter<Historique> writerHistorique() {
    JsonFileItemWriter<Historique> writerHistorique = new JsonFileItemWriter<>(
        new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/Insee.json"),
        new JsonObjectMarshaller<Historique>() {
          @Override
          public String marshal(Historique object) {
            try {
              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
              return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;
            }
          }
        }) {
      @Override
      public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
          throws ItemStreamException {
        super.open(executionContext);
        try {
          getOutputState().write(",{Historique: } [");
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      }
    };
    writerHistorique.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/java/output/Insee.json"));
    writerHistorique.setAppendAllowed(true);
    writerHistorique.setJsonObjectMarshaller(new JsonObjectMarshaller<Historique>() {
      @Override
      public String marshal(Historique item) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("parent", item.getParent());
        map.put("typecom_av", item.getTypecom_av());
        map.put("mod", item.getMod());
        map.put("nccenr_av", item.getLibelle_av());
        map.put("nccenr_av", item.getLibelle_ap());
        map.put("date_eff", item.getDate_eff());
        return map.toString();
      }
    });
    return writerHistorique;
  }

I don't know if they should each have their own ItemWriter or if I should write them in just one. City ​​and history each have their class

Did you try implement your own ItemReader that fetch both files to the record that you need be written?
Ok now I understand. You need to do that in 3 steps

Step 1: read City and write it in a DB
Step 2: read the history add it to the city and write that in the db
Step 3: read the db and write it to json file


yes I tried but I'm new to coding and spring batch and I didn't succeed. maybe I did it wrong

OK. Can you explain what you are trying to acheive and what is not working?

I added elements which I hope will clarify my request

I don't have to use a database. the goal is only to process data, it should not be stored in db

You can use a file repository as long it can provide you a search feature

Yes of course. I have to read my cities.txt file which has this structure:
"typecom","com","reg","dep","arr","tncc","ncc","nccenr","libelle","can","comparent"
COM,"01001","84","01","012","5",ABERGEMENT CLEMENCIAT,Abergement-Clémenciat,L'Abergement-Clémenciat,"0108",
COM,"01002","84","01","011","5",ABERGEMENT DE VAREY,Abergement-de-Varey,L'Abergement-de-Varey,"0101",

then I have to read my history.txt file which has this structure:
mod,date_eff,typecom_av,com_av,tncc_av,ncc_av,nccenr_av,libelle_av,typecom_ap,com_ap,tncc_ap,ncc_ap,nccenr_ap,libelle_ap

32,2019-03-01,COM,45287,0,SAINT LOUP DE GONOIS,Saint-Loup-de-Gonois,Saint-Loup-de-Gonois,COMD,45287,0,SAINT LOUP DE GONOIS,Saint-Loup-de-Gonois,Saint-Loup-de-Gonois
32,2019-03-01,COM,45287,0,SAINT LOUP DE GONOIS,Saint-Loup-de-Gonois,Saint-Loup-de-Gonois,COM,45307,3,SELLE SUR LE BIED,Selle-sur-le-Bied,La Selle-sur-le-Bied.
and I have to rewrite them in json format so that each city if it has a "com" number identical to the "com_av" history then following this city its history appears. like that :
 {
    "status" : "DELEGATE",
    "insee" : "50417",
    "parent" : "50417",
    "country" : "fr",
    "dept" : "",
    "historics" : [ {
      "parent" : "50417",
      "typeModeNumber" : "32",
      "typemod" : "COM",
      "label" : "Quettehou",
      "oldLabel" : "Morsalines",
      "dateEffet" : "2019-01-01"
    }    

I skip the part where I process the data to display only what I need. but for the moment in the code that I gave I read the two files and when I write them I display all the cities and then all the histories. and that's not what I want.
